# Firebase Database not loading data offline

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that uses Firebase Database in offline mode (by calling `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)`). In the database there is a node that user can access only if value in other node is set to true, the rules look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".read": "false",
    "mynode": {
      "$dataId": {
        ".read": "auth != null && root.child('userAccessNode/' + auth.uid + '/' + $dataId).val() == true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works correctly when device is connected to internet. However when I turn flight mode on the device the callback `addValueEventListener(ValueEventListener)` doesn't return anything - nor error, not value, just hangs until I turn on internet connection again.

I made sure that both nodes were retrieved before going offline, so I was sure the node in question and node holding access information was cached.

For other nodes that have simple rules like (auth != null) offline mode works fine, but not in this case.

Am I doing anything wrong? Any idea how can I make this work? How does rules (that depend on other nodes) evaluation work when offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database security rules are always evaluated on the server side.  This prevents malicious clients from bypassing those rules.

Comment: does it mean the 'secured' nodes are not accessible offline even though they were accessible seconds before going flight mode? this seems at least a little strange and inconsistent. 
I would expect the user to be able to access offline everything that was available to him when device was last online.

Comment: that also doesn't explain why from two nodes (one with complex rule as above, one with just checking for user being logged in), I can get offline data only for one of them and not for other?

Comment: If you're offline, Firebase also cannot check if the current authentication token is valid.  Tokens expire after an hour and the device must be online to refresh it.  Please bear in mind that Firebase was not intended to be used offline.  It just happens to support some optimizations for certain offline use cases.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. I understand that rules are evaluated on the server side. But why client doesn't get data offline which are already synced, just have complex security rules?